# Pre-filling a prompt in Bash

Tags: bash

Writing a bash script, and I want to get user input. Awesome,

```
read -p "What directory should we save in? " -e FOLDER
```

Except that what I'd like to do, *ideally*, is have the user see something like:

```
What directory should we save in? /home/user/default/
```

with the cursor at the end of the line, and the ability to delete backwards or append or whatever. Essentially, pre-filling the user's input, but giving them the ability to edit it.

Readline obviously has the capability, but it appears to be not exposed in the `read` command. Any alternatives? I'd prefer to not have to use perl or such.

The constraint I'm working under is that I'm writing a single shell script that would be nice to disseminate widely, so should rely on as little pre-existing infrastructure as possible. `rlwrap` and `read -i` both work *if* their dependencies (`rlwrap` and bash version >> whatever I have, respectively) are available. Both good answers, choose whichever works for you.

Comment: which version of bash?  run `bash --version`

Comment: @Foo Bah - I want it to work in as many versions of bash as possible. Ideal would probably even be eventually to not depend on bash, but get along with sh okay.

Comment: rlwrap is your friend :)

Comment: @Foo That would mean adding a dependency... also not thrilled about that. I think the answer is to check for Bash version and use -i if available, otherwise use rlwrap if available, otherwise... leave it up to the user to type ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the command in rlwrap, which provides instant readline capabilities: https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap

(rlwrap -P does what you want)

As far as a pure bash solution is concerned for the 3.2 line (which i am presuming you are using), I dont think its possible

Comment: The link here is broken. However, it appears that this GitHub repository is the new home of rlwrap. Also, for the curious, here is an example:$ folder=$(rlwrap -S "What directory should we save in? " -P /home/user/default/ -o cat)

Answer (score 16):

```
$ read -p "What directory should we save in? " -i "/home/user/default/" -e FOLDER
What directory should we save in? /home/user/default/
```

that should work, right?

Comment: read -i is not provided in bash 3.2.25 (rhel5.5) or 3.2.48 (snow leopard)

Comment: I guess that got added sometime between then and 4.1, which is what I have

Comment: Cool, but yeah, not supported in the version of Bash I have, and I want this to be compatible (hence my reticence to use something like perl, though that's probably widespread enough that I could rely on it).

Comment: did you build bash from source or did it come with a distro?  [I ended up rebuilding 4.1.0 on SL]

Comment: @Foo Mine came with ubuntu 10.04