# Pre-filling a prompt in Rust

Tags: rust, io

This question has been asked before for [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029848/pre-filling-a-prompt-in-bash) and Ruby, but I can't find any information for Rust.

I have a string that needs to be changed very slightly, so I want to be able to pre-fill it in the command line and then prompt for user input using [read_line](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html).

Is there any way to do this in Rust?